I'm unable to get the package for android app
Failed to transform progressview-1.0.1.aar (com.white:progressview:1.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-jni, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
\\\> Could not find progressview-1.0.1.aar (com.white:progressview:1.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/white/progressview/1.0.1/progressview-1.0.1.aar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/white/progressview/1.0.1/progressview-1.0.1.jar


The package you are looking for, found here, is very old.
It has not  been maintained in over 7 years.
Also, JCenter has been made read only since March 31, 2021 and it seems like  the library you are trying to use is not there.
I can suggest looking for a more recent and maintained library that does what you are looking for.

I was search in jcenter also its not available recent packages

@MohamedAbdulKadar - As I suggested, look for another library that does what this library did. If my answer helped you, please mark it so others an find it more easily.
